# Remove "padding" around layer similar to Image->Trim with PS CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I used the selection tool to drag part of one image onto another image in a new layer.  That layer has a "padding" (not sure what else to call it) of about 75 transparent pixels around the image.  I'm wondering if there's a way to remove the transparent pixels for that layer alone similar to the way one can use Image->Trim on the entire image.  The purpose for doing this is so I can make an image sprite with each icon on a layer of the same size.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transparency is there because of a lack of painted pixels, so in this case you would not be "removing" the transparency, but rather filling in those areas.

If you place a new layer under the layer in question, and fill it with the appropriate color, and then merge the 2 layers, you will have a layer that extends to the edges of the canvas.

Comment: thank you for your response and this will work for certain situations.  perhaps my wording is a bit off in what I'm actually asking so I'll try again.  The trim function can crop an image using a bounding box around the outside edges of painted pixels.  Is there a way to trim the surrounding transparent pixels from an individual layer?  In other words, is there a way to crop an individual layer to a bounding box surrounding that layer's painted pixels?  edit: clarity (?)

Comment: You cannot remove transparent pixels. The item on that layer already is cropped to that. TO select that, you can ctrl+click on the layer thumbnail in the layers palette. If you can provide some example of the item or a mockup exhibiting a similar problem, please do.